# How to re-run a Spring Batch job?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have defined a Spring Batch job which runs once just fine. However it is unable to run a second time due to a duplicate entry in the primary key for the JOB_INSTANCE_ID;

```
SEVERE: Job Terminated in error: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT into    BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION) values (?, ?, ?, ?)]; Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I've read that this can be over-come by setting command line parameters on the job, e.g.

```
java -cp ${CLASSPATH} org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner myJob.xml myJob date=20121025154016 -next
```

Whether I include the -next parameter or not, it will not run the job.

My Spring Batch configuration looks as follows (batch/launchContext.xml);

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd
http://springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Launch context: how to launch all of the jobs -->
    <!-- Expects a data source configuration file to be used, with a DataSource bean 
called "dataSource" -->

    <!-- The data source for the jobs status -->
    <import resource="dataSource.xml" />

    <bean
            id="jobRepository"                        
class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
            <property
                    name="dataSource"
                    ref="dataSource" />
            <property
                    name="databaseType"
                    value="MySQL" />
            <property
                    name="transactionManager"
                    ref="transactionManager"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean
            id="incrementer"
            class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer" />

    <bean
            id="jobLauncher"
            class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
            <property
                    name="jobRepository"
                    ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>

    <bean
            id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
            <property
                    name="dataSource"
                    ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean
            id="jobExplorer"       
class="org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.JobExplorerFactoryBean">
            <property
                    name="dataSource"
                    ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

And the job is like this (in the myJob.xml file)

```
....
<import resource="batch/launchContext.xml" />
...
    <batch:job
            id="myJob"
            job-repository="jobRepository"
            incrementer="incrementer">
            <batch:step id="step1">
                    <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
                            <batch:chunk
                                    reader="myReader"
                                    processor="myProcessor"
                                    writer="myWriter"
                                    commit-interval="10" />
                    </batch:tasklet>
            </batch:step>
    </batch:job>
```

Ideally what I'd like is each run of the job to be persisted with the run date/time. Is there a way to configure the launcher to do this automatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd also placed this question on the official Spring Forums.  And I eventually found my own answer (with a hint along the way);

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?131347-How-to-re-run-a-job&p=428484#post428484

In short, the problem was that I'd deleted the value '0' from these three tables;

- BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_SEQ
- BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_SEQ
- BATCH_JOB_SEQ

So when cleaning out the Spring Batch Meta-Data tables (e.g. using truncate or delete from ...) ensure the following commands are run afterwards;

```
INSERT INTO BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_SEQ values(0);
INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_SEQ values(0);
INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_SEQ values(0);
```